# Configuring a VNC Desktop: Upgrading GUI from classic gnome desktop to newest gnome desktop

Tags: vnc

I have a vnc system, I was able to build. It leverages the classic gnome desktop GUI.

[image]

I would like to upgrade the `.vnc/xstartups` file, to use the newest Gnome Desktop Environment. The Ubuntu Gnome Desktop featured as the official Ubuntu 18.04 desktop.

Here is my current ~/.vnc/xstartups file.

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-session &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
gnome-terminal &
```

Thank you, please keep the comments and answer to the topic.

- This question assumes a working VNC connection, with no errors.
- This question is specific, as in no question to the purpose of this is necessary, I believe it's clear that the point is to have a newer GUI desktop environment.
- If you don't know (A.K.A. "It's not possible"), join the club. Let's wait, for the person who does know how, to give the answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution was using Xfce4, I installed the packages for the desktop environment and built a simple `xstartups` file which just initiates the desktop.

Here are the instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04

[image]
I was really looking to have this setup type but with the Official Ubuntu Gnome Desktop

Answer (score 0):

One solution was using KDE, I installed the packages for the desktop environment and built a simple xstartups file which just initiates the desktop.
[image: So nice!]
Instructions:

Somewhat based, on https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server
Here are the libraries, from a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential openssh-server tightvncserver kubuntu-desktop xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi`

After the install and a reboot. Login and navigate to the base directory. `cd ~`, run `tightvncserver :1` command and initialize the configuration.

Now run `tightvncserver -kill :1` to shutdown the vnc server.

Let's make the config changes.

Run `sudo rm -rf .vnc/xstartup && touch .vnc/xstartup && sudo chmod +x .vnc/xstartup` to delete the file, and recreate it with the correct file properties.

Ok, now jump into the editor and make a couple edits. `sudo nano .vnc/xstartup`

Enter this as the file contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Config
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

# Settings
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XKB_DEFAULT_RULES=base
export QT_XKB_CONFIG_ROOT=/usr/share/X11/xkb
# Locale
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL=

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
plasmashell &
startx
```

type <`Ctrl` + `x`> for the menu and type `y` to save and hit `Enter` to exit.

One more, `touch ~/.xinitxc && sudo nano ~/.xinitrc` to create a basic X Server Initialization profile.

Add this line to the file:

```
startkde
```

type <`Ctrl` + `x`> for the menu and type `y` to save and hit `Enter` to exit.

Now save whatever your output to `hostname` is, then in some client computer with interfacing access to the computer where all of this was configured in.

Download a vnc viewer, I prefer RealVNC viewer. I am not associated with the company, in any way.
https://www.realvnc.com/en/connecan/download/viewer/

While that is downloading, open a ssh connection to the computer. Follow this guide.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

While logged in to the shell on the remote computer.
Start the vncserver as before with `tightvncserver -compatiblekbd :1`

Leave that open.

Enter in to the login bar in that client computer, in the RealVNC, the hostname output. Like so:

`hostnamehere:1` (<= hostnamehere is the output) and connect. Login with your regular user and enjoy.

I was really looking to have this setup type but with the Official Ubuntu Gnome Desktop

Comment: Currently, this needs a fix, for the keyboard, which works within applications like Firefox, but does not work in the console, etc...

Comment: Might be something that is easy to fix, with Xmanager5,
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3713#issuecomment-338086681